# Does the player level affect anything in Family Guy: Quest for Stuff?

Tags: family-guy-the-quest-for-stuff

In Family Guy: Quest for Stuff, you have an overall player level that you earn experience for. I'm puzzled as to what effect it has on the game.

Is it related to which character quests open up, or which items are available to purchase (as in Tapped Out, which the game obviously draws influence from), or is it just a vanity stat to show how long you've been playing?

Comment: I think some buildings and scenery might be locked until you reach a certain player level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain actions that can only be unlocked by achieving a certain level. Aside from that, level doesn't mean much at all. Different characters even have different maximum levels, and I've not found any rhyme or reason as to why, except perhaps they have more actions available (some of which require a higher level).